# Can arbitrary objects be thrown as errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

Douglas Cockford insists that it must be an "exception object with two properties: a `name`, and a `message`.

Is this just him FUDing again, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, arbitrary objects can be thrown. Try it:

```
throw 5;
```

Comment: I did, but I was still wondering about edge cases or if there was any other underlying non-obvious-on-the-surface that I wasn't aware of yet.

Comment: @adlwalrus: I don't know of any.